# MYSQL if a field return 0 then select another query and join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello guys i have these tables;

```
USERS( user_id ,fullname ,username etc.)

POSTS ( post_id, user_id, post, orig_post_id, replyto date)

USER_PROFILE (id, user_id, profile_image_path etc)
```

Examples

```
USERS (1 ,John Doe ,johndoe etc.),( 2 ,Stack Flow ,stackflow etc.)

POSTS (2, 1, My naame is John doe and i approve this message, 0, 0,sometimestamp),
      (3, 12, My naame is Stack Flow and i approve this message, 0, 2,sometimestamp)

USER_PROFILE (1, 1, ppdjodjf.jpg etc),(2, 2, grsdjodjf.jpg etc)
```

Basically, i want the query to output this if the replyto field is 0

```
array('post_id' => 2, 
'user_id' => 1, 
'post' => the post, 
'orig_post_id,' => 0
'replyto,' => 0
username => johndoe,
fullname => John Doe,
profile_image_path => etc)
```

And when it's not zero

```
array('post_id' => 3, 
'user_id' => 2, 
'post' => Another post, 
'orig_post_id,' => 0
'replyto,' => 2
username => stackflow,
fullname => Stack Flow,
profile_image_path => etc,
'replies' => array(all the replies)
```

Comment: Can you show how the final results set should look like? (based on the sampel data that you have provided above)

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question, i just edited it.

Comment: not sufficient. Describe in clean english sentence e.g "show me post from user x and/or posts are  replied from x user " and also put your schema description for all tables in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending the whole day on this, My code ended up looking like this.

```
  public function get_connected_post()
    {
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');

        $sql = "SELECT  p.*,up.fullname,u.username,upi.file_path_thumb,IF(hi5c.hi5_count is NULL,'0',hi5c.hi5_count) AS count_hi5,
                        IF(brn.branch_count is NULL,'0',brn.branch_count) AS count_branch, IF(rply.reply_count is NULL,'0',rply.reply_count) AS count_reply,
                        IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_highfives ph WHERE ph.user_id = $user_id AND ph.post_id = p.post_id),'1','0') AS count_is_hi5ed,
                        IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts pt WHERE pt.user_id = $user_id AND pt.is_branch_of_id = p.post_id),'1','0') AS count_is_branched
                FROM    (
                         SELECT  user_id
                         FROM    user_followers
                         WHERE   follower_id = $user_id
                         UNION ALL
                         SELECT  $user_id
                        ) uf
                JOIN    posts p
                ON      p.user_id = uf.user_id
                JOIN   user_profile up
                ON     up.user_id = p.user_id
                JOIN user_profile_images upi
                ON     upi.image_id = up.profile_image_id
                JOIN users u
                ON     u.user_id = p.user_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ph.post_id, count(*) AS hi5_count
                                 FROM post_highfives ph
                                 GROUP BY ph.post_id) hi5c
                ON p.post_id = hi5c.post_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT pst.post_id,pst.is_branch_of_id, count(*) AS branch_count
                                 FROM posts pst
                                 GROUP BY pst.is_branch_of_id) brn
                ON p.post_id = brn.is_branch_of_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT pst.post_id,pst.reply_to, count(*) AS reply_count
                                 FROM posts pst
                                 GROUP BY pst.reply_to) rply
                ON p.post_id = rply.reply_to
                ORDER BY p.post_date DESC";


        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if ($query) {
            $result = array();
                foreach($query->result_array() as $r){
                    $branch_id = $r['is_branch_of_id'];
                    if($branch_id != 0){
                        $branch_array = $this->branch_query($this->postid_return_user_id($branch_id),$branch_id);
                    }else{
                        $branch_array = array();
                    }
                    $result[] = array_merge((array)$branch_array, (array)$r);
                }
            return $result;
        }
         else {
            return false;
        }


    }
```

I know this looks different from the question i asked but i was trying to simplfy what i was actually doing.I didn't think asking a question stating this problem would get me anywhere, although simplyfying the question still didn't get me anywhere as no one understood me haha. For my question anyway, the relevant part is the last bit of the code where i put a condition ssaying if branch_id is not zero get some array data and if it is return an empty array.The I merged the array together with then query result.
Now i have to think of how i can simplyfy this.

Answer (score 1):

These are basics in SQL.  You really should learn some SQL.
It's easy to learn, you could spend half an hour on it, and it would be very beneficial.

First, the posts for a given user would be:

```
select posts.*
from posts
where posts.user_id = '$user_id'
```

To get the user fields you want, do a join

```
select posts.*,users.username,users.fullname
from posts
  inner join users where posts.user_id = users.user_id
where posts.user_id = '$user_id'
```

You should be able to figure out how to join to user_profile to get those fields.

To filter only those records without orig_post_id, you might need to test for zero,
or you might need to test for NULL.  Maybe both, so assuming you want to test for both:

```
where posts.user_id = '$user_id'
  and (orig_post_id = 0 or orig_post_id is null)
```

Comment: Sorry not that much of a newb. I probably didn't make myself clear enough.

Comment: Sorry for not structuring the question properly @Marlin i feel like i wasted your time. But thanks anyways.